# How to center a button on the navigation bar using react-native-router-flux?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm using react-native-router-flux for navigation in my app, I've managed to create buttons on the left (hamburger menu) and right on the navigation bar, however I also need a button in the center of the bar, how can I do this ?

Att

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by creating a navbar from scratch only. It was not complicated. Thank you router-flux for making this prop